# Resharper - How to turn off 'private' access modifier?

Tags: settings, resharper

I don't like having 'private' placed before my access modifiers. They're all private by default anyways and it's just visual clutter.

How do I turn off resharper constantly tagging everything with 'private'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ReSharper 9.1**

ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Modifiers -> Use explicit private modifier (Un-Check)

[image]

**ReSharper 2016.1
ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Modifiers ->

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct setting. I've modified this setting, saved it, and yet Resharper is still inserting the private modifier evrey time.

Answer (score 7):

In the ReSharper Options menu, go to Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other and disable explicit private modifier.

[image]